# Play framework - NullPointerException during auto-recompile in dev mode

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

I am getting the following exception every time I make changes to my code while the application is running in dev mode and make a server request that causes the code to recompile. If I exit the play console and start it again, everything works fine... until the next time it has to recompile. It seems to be having some trouble with the project jar files, but I can't really figure it out beyond that. I am using Play 2.1.2 on Windows 8 and I have disabled auto-build in the IDE (Eclipse).

I should note that I have recently had to switch to a slower machine, and I wasn't experiencing this previously. There is no difference in set up as far as I can think of.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException:
    java.util.zip.ZipFile.getZipEntry(Unknown Source)
    java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$900(Unknown Source)
    java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.nextElement(Unknown Source)
    java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.nextElement(Unknown Source)
    java.util.jar.JarFile$1.nextElement(Unknown Source)
    java.util.jar.JarFile$1.nextElement(Unknown Source)
    org.reflections.vfs.ZipDir$1$1.computeNext(ZipDir.java:35)
    org.reflections.vfs.ZipDir$1$1.computeNext(ZipDir.java:33)
    com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
    com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
    org.reflections.Reflections.scan(Reflections.java:165)
    org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:94)
    play.libs.Classpath.getReflections(Classpath.java:48)
    play.libs.Classpath.getTypes(Classpath.java:25)
    play.db.ebean.EbeanPlugin.onStart(EbeanPlugin.java:62)
    play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:68)
    play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:68)
    scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:309)
    play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:68)
    play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:68)
    play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:68)
    play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18)
    play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:67)
    play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:141)
    play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:114)
    scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:114)
    play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112)
    scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:523)
    play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112)
    play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:104)
    scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: more details please. Play version? OS? is auto build enabled with IDE?

Comment: Play version is 2.1.2 on Windows 8 and I have disabled auto-build in the IDE (Eclipse). (Updated the question to include this information.)

Comment: @mhusaini try a `play clean` command and see how that works.

Comment: @kingdamian42, I have already tried that; didn't help :(

Comment: @mhusaini Hmm. Try re-installing play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have a corrupt Jar somewhere.  Reinstalling Play will refresh all of the Jars that Play is using.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error
(I even created play's issue on github https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/4525)

Later I found the solution for my case:

In build.sbt I have options:

```
// SECTION: Build package configuration
serverLoading in Debian  := SystemV
maintainer in Debian  := "me"
packageSummary in Debian  := "App"
packageDescription := "App"
exportJars := true
defaultLinuxInstallLocation := "/var"
// /SECTION: Build package configuration
```

If I remove exportJars param my app feel good on Windows.